# How to fix a webm file without audio?

Tags: ffmpeg, mediarecorder, webm

I use mediarecorder to record video and audio from a user's browser. We record every 15 seconds and then upload that blog to S3. Then we combine all the files together to make one webm file. I believe the first file isn't right because when I combine the files, there is not any audio - only video.

Is there a way to alter the headers in the first file to use the audio in all of the subsequent files? OR is there an FFMPEG command to force using the audio? I know they exist in the other files.

I don't believe this is important but here is the code that I use to save and combine the webm blobs.

First I save the blobs from the media recorder

```
  recorder = new MediaRecorder(local_media_stream.remoteStream, {
               mimeType: encoding_options,
               audioBitsPerSecond: 96000,
               videoBitsPerSecond: bits_per_second,
            });
  recorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
          that.save_blob(e.data, blob_index);      
         }
```

Then later I combine each of those blobs.

```
bucket = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region:'us-east-1').bucket("files")

keys = bucket.objects(prefix: "files").collect(&:key)

temp_webm_file = Tempfile.new(['total', '.webm'])
keys.each_with_index do |key, index|
    temp_webm_file.write bucket.object(key).get.body.read
end
temp_webm_file.close()
```

One thing I know that fixes the issue is if I combine a short webm file with audio to the very beginning. Then the audio all works.

Comment: Can you please post a sample WebM file? (I know you probably can't post the specific file you like to restore). Please try to create a file with the same issue that you can share.

Comment: Yea I will get an example loaded tomorrow!